# Calling an activity on HomeScreenWidget click

Tags: android, widget, onclick

I am trying to open my activity when a user clicks on a button in my HomeScreen Widget. But I guess the app is not responding to my onclick. Here is my code snippet :

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.layout_appwidget);  
Intent launchActivity = new Intent();
launchActivity.setClass(context,UpdatesScreen.class);
launchActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, launchActivity, 0);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.iv_widget, pendingIntent);
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyAppWidgetProvider.class.getName());
AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```

I have copied the same code in onUpdate as well as onEnabled method of MyAppWidgetProvider class. But still it's not working at all.

I have read many post regarding this issue but all are using the same code. Am I doing something wrong?? What is the right way to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the R.layout.layout_appwidget?

Comment: Hi Guys, I have found the mistake. I was overriding both the method onUpdate() as well as onReceive(). If we override onReceive(), in that case onUpdate() never gets called. and I wasn't using "ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE" as an action in onReceive too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the mistake. Posting my answer to help someone facing the same issue.

Actually, I was overriding both the method `onUpdate()` as well as `onReceive()`. If we override `onReceive()`, in that case `onUpdate()` never gets called. and I wasn't using `ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE` as an action in `onReceive()` too.